image display dissapear on predict page
i finnaly reached solution  with help of brave  users here, but here is  one remaining problem  and plase help me if it is possible of course, so here is html  code :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Select image</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{{ url_for('predict')}}"  enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post">
        <label for="img">Select image</label>
        <input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/*" onchange="displayImage(this)">
        <br>
        <img id="selectedImg" src="#" alt="Selected Image" style="display:none; max-width: 300px;">
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <script>
        function displayImage(input) {
            var file = input.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var imgElement = document.getElementById('selectedImg');
                imgElement.src = e.target.result;
                imgElement.style.display = 'block';
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    </script>
<h4 style="color:Violet;">
                   {{ prediction_text }} </h4>
</body>
</html>

and correspondng python code :
from flask import (
    Flask,
    render_template,
    request
)
import cv2
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("Select_IMage.html")


@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict():
    text = 'Please select and upload a file.'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files.get('img')
        print(file.filename)
        file_path =os.path.join("static/Image",file.filename)
        image =cv2.imread(file_path,0)
        print(image.shape)
        if file and file.filename != '':
            text=f'my image has shape {image.shape}'
    return render_template('Select_IMage.html', prediction_text=text)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

when we run it, e get :

it looks fine right? when i will press submit, it will generate following result :

shape of image is  shown, but image itself lost, how can i keep image on predict page as well?

You need to save you resultant image in a directory in your flask app and then return then use img src tag to display. Example with static directory. <img src="{{ url_for('static', fname) }}"
